# Can I still decline an accepted counter offer before signing a contract?

Tags: faculty-application, tenure-track, professorship

I am currently in a tenure-track assistant professor (AP) position. About one month ago, I got an AP position offer from a better ranked university, with a good startup package. When I informed my current department of the offer, the head wanted me to stay. They eventually came up with an acceptable counter offer.

Without deep thoughts and given the short time window for decision, I indicated I would stay. They are starting to prepare a contract/formal retention offer for me to sign. But now I have second thoughts and came to realize I prefer the external offer. So I wondered if I still have the freedom to change my mind at this moment, given that I have already expressed my acceptance of the counter offer? I haven't turned down the external offer yet. How can this situation be dealt with?

Comment: This may be a local, legal, question. Some verbal agreements might be binding (some places), especially if the other party has spent resources due to the agreement. Consult a lawyer to be sure.

Comment: Can you suggest a suitable place for this question? Thanks

Comment: For local, legal questions a suitable person to ask would be a lawyer.

Comment: The question itself isn't out of bounds but, but personal linked information can be found by those you don't want to see it, and legal advice here is worth exactly what you've paid for it. Good Luck.

Comment: Workplace SE may be another place. The general opinion there will be 'never take a counter-offer'...

Comment: You don’t have a counter offer yet - you are told one is coming. Until you have it in writing and have signed it, you don’t need to apologize for not taking it. What if the actual offer isn’t what was verbally offered?

Comment: If there is a counter offer, there should be a proposed contract shown to you. And then you sign the contract, or you don't. It's up to you. If you signed, you signed. If you didn't, you didn't. And yes, workplace.stackexchange which should have more expertise in this area, will tell you to never accept a counter offer. There are very good reasons for that.

Comment: can you shed some light on the reasons? I head some reasons for industrial positions. I am not sure if the same applies for academia. Thanks! At this moment, I haven't got the contract yet. My department went through the details about the counter offer with me and I indicated my decision to stay in an email.